# I'm wasting a day on dates

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having problems since I am saving some dates and they are saved well in the database, when I show them I have one day left, for example if I enter 09/30/2020 it shows me 09/29/2020, I have tried some solutions like adding T00: 00: 00 but that makes an invalid date, plus the backend is taking care of that. Here's a bit of my code, in case someone can give me a hand.

```
 showDatesDependingOnWhichExists = (status) =>{
  if(status.estimatedDate != undefined || "" && status.comment == undefined || "" && 
  status.startDate == undefined || "" && status.finishDate == undefined || "" ){
    return (<td>{moment(new Date(status.estimatedDate)).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}</td>)
  }else if(status.startDate != undefined || "" && 
  status.finishDate != undefined || "" && status.comment == undefined || "" ){
    return (<td>{moment(new Date(status.startDate)).format('DD / MM / YYYY') + "  -  " + moment(new Date(status.finishDate)).format('DD / MM / YYYY')}</td>)
  }else if(status.comment != undefined || "" ){
    return (<td>{moment(new Date(status.startDate)).format('DD / MM / YYYY') + "  -  " + moment(new Date(status.finishDate)).format('DD / MM / YYYY')}</td>)
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the database is observed in UTC

Comment: This is the format: 2020-09-30T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: Unrelated but moment doesn’t need you to supply a Date object.  You can pass a date string to moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast it to UTC mode using `.utc`, otherwise it would use your local timezone to parse the date

The [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) states that

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`

```js
const time = "2020-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"

console.log(moment.utc(time).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was just looking at this documentation, I tried it and it worked for me, thank you very much, what you say is the correct answer, thank you all for your time !!

Answer (score 1):

I think @AbdulMoeez is correct in his comment to your question.  You are likely storing the date as UTC in the database or inadvertently converting it to UTC in the server layer.  Then you display it as the local time zone in the client, which is causing it to (correctly) display as a different date.